# Inputting value on 2D Float arrays with for loops

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to make a 2D array that has 2 column and some row. The first column is inputted by using scanf is the radius, while the second column are dependent on the first column is the area.

I already tried to leave them out of loops (manual input) then output them immediately but somehow only the last and first input are correct

```
#define circlecol 1
#define circlerow 1

int main() {
    float circles[circlerow][circlecol];
    for(int x = 0; x <= circlerow; x++) {
        scanf("%f", &circles[x][0]);
        circles[x][1] = 3.14*circles[x][0]*circles[x][0];
    }`
```

With the input of 8 and 3 I expected this to be the output

Your Circle:
        8.000000        200.960000
        3.000000        28.260000

But I get this instead

Your Circle:
        8.000000        0.000000
        0.000000        28.260000

The format was

Your Circle: [0][0] [0][1] [1][0] [1][1]

Comment: Show how the array is declared.

Comment: It seems you need to use the following loop for(int x = 0; x < circlerow; x++)

Comment: What output? Please show a bit more code here so we can see the full picture.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow already editted it

@tadman I use normal 2D array output
`for(int i = 0; i <= circlerow; i++) {
printf("\n");
  
for(int j = 0; j <= circlecol; j++ ) {
   
printf("\t%f", circles[i][j]);
  }
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This array

```
float circles[circlerow][circlecol];
```

in fact is declared as

```
float circles[1][1];
```

that is it has one row and one column that is only one element that can be accessed using expression `circle[0][0]`.

It seems you mean the following

```
#define circlecol 2
#define circlerow 2

int main( void ) {
    float circles[circlerow][circlecol];
    for(int x = 0; x < circlerow; x++) {
        scanf("%f", &circles[x][0]);
        circles[x][1] = 3.14*circles[x][0]*circles[x][0];
    }
}
```

That is the array shall have two rows and two columns.

Comment: ah, it works, but didn't it mean really the same thing?, I mean since array start from 0, and ends in 2, you just make the for loop using < instead of <= and increase array size?, 

i mean array[x][y] has the size of x+1 and y+1 right?

Comment: @AldiandyaIrsyadNurFarizi no, `array[x][y]` has the size of `x` and `y`. `array[0][0]` is the element in the 1st row and 1st column, and `array[x - 1][y - 1]` is the element in the last column and in the last row.

Comment: @AldiandyaIrsyadNurFarizi If an array has N elements then the valid range of indices is [0, N). So you have to add one more row and column and use the condition in the loop c < circlerow. In this case valid indices will be 0 and 1 that is they both less than circlerow.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
for(int x = 0; x <= circlerow; x++)
```

to this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < circlerow; x++)
```

since array indexing starts from 0 and ends at size of array - 1.

Similarly, you would do `for(int j = 0; j < circlecol; j++)`.

In general, if an array is declared as:

```
array[rows][cols]
```

then its dimensions are `rows x cols`. `array[0][0]` is the element in the 1st row and 1st column, and `array[rows - 1][cols - 1]` is the element in the last column and in the last row.

---

Minimal complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define circlecol 1
#define circlerow 1

int main(void) {
  float circles[circlerow][circlecol];
  for(int x = 0; x < circlerow; x++) {
    scanf("%f", &circles[x][0]);
    circles[x][1] = 3.14*circles[x][0]*circles[x][0];
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < circlerow; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < circlecol; j++)
      printf("%f", circles[i][j]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I used circlerow as the array itself

So number of circle row is actually 2, but I input it as one,
I already edited my post for the array format.

Comment: @AldiandyaIrsyadNurFarizi I saw it, see my updated answer, I believe it works now. :)